# SQL Reporting Services Tree Navigation using Web Service API in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, ssrs-2008

Need to develop Tree navigation of sql reporting services using Web Service API in ASP.NET MVC 4.0. Tried this, http://odetocode.com/articles/95.aspx and successfully test the code in asp.net web application. Now I'm trying to do the same mvc using web service 'ReportService2010' and jquery treeview. 
This was sample code controller side `

```
    public static string ReportPath
    {
        get { return "/SSRSTest1"; }
    }
    public static char[] PathSeparatorArray
    {
        get { return pathSeparatorArray; }
    }

    public static string PathSeparatorString
    {
        get { return pathSeparatorString; }
    }

    protected static char pathSeparator = '/';
    protected static char[] pathSeparatorArray = { pathSeparator };
    protected static string pathSeparatorString = new string(pathSeparator, 1);`

    public ActionResult SSRSReportStructureInfo(string root)
    {
        ReportingService2010 rService = new ReportingService2010();
        rService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        CatalogItem[] catalogItems;
        catalogItems = rService.ListChildren(ReportPath, true);
        List<TreeViewNode> nodes = new List<TreeViewNode>();
        nodes = BuildTree(catalogItems);
        return Json(nodes);
    }
     private List<TreeViewNode> BuildTree(CatalogItem[] catalogItems)
    {
        nodesList = new List<TreeViewNode>();
        foreach (CatalogItem item in catalogItems)
        {
            List<TreeViewNode> nodes = new List<TreeViewNode>();
            if (item.TypeName == "Report")
            {
                string path = item.Path.Remove(0, ReportPath.Length);
                string[] tokens = path.Split(PathSeparatorArray);
                BuildNodesFromTokens(tokens, 0, nodes);
                foreach (var child in nodes)
                {
                    nodesList.Add(new TreeViewNode()
                    {
                        text = child.text
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return nodesList;
    }
     private void BuildNodesFromTokens(string[] tokens, int index, List<TreeViewNode> nodes)
    {
        TreeViewNode node = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i].text == tokens[index])
            {
                node = nodes[i];

                break;
            }
        }
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new TreeViewNode();
            node.text = tokens[index];
            nodes.Add(node);

        }

        index++;
        if (tokens.Length > index)
        {
            BuildNodesFromTokens(tokens, index, nodes);
        }
    }
```

In Index View:

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-treeview-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-treeview-async-0.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul id="fileSystemInfos" class="filetree"></ul><br />
<div id="fileSystemInfosControl"><a href="?#">Collapse All</a> | <a href="?#">Expand All</a></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#fileSystemInfos').treeview({
         url: '/Home/SSRSReportStructureInfo',
         ajax: {
             type: 'post'
         },
         control: '#fileSystemInfosControl'
     })
 });
</script>
```

Unable to add the child in the parent in the jquery treeview. Suggestion??

Comment: What is #fileSystemInfosControl? can it handle SSRSReportStructureInfo?

Comment: It's just the control to expand or collapse the jquery treeview.

Comment: Can you trace your result from /Home/SSRSReportStructureInfo?